# Why are linked lists preferred over arrays in some applications?

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list

Why can't I store everything in contiguous memory using pointer arithmetic and `malloc()` and using null character to represent end of list (like in array)?

I textbook I am referring to suggests me to use linked lists to store terms of polynomials or digits of very large numbers. Why can't I use the above approach for these applications?

Comment: What makes you think that isn’t an option?

Comment: Who says you can’t?

Comment: They are not. Please explain, in several paragraphs of written English, with some [mre] and some benchmarks, why you think they are.... See also [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and study for inspiration the source code of several open source C programs (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: Linked lists and arrays are useful in different types of applications.

Comment: You can... until you run out of the memory in the block that you have allocated, and need to allocate a larger block.

Comment: This is like asking "which is better, a hammer or a screwdriver?"

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Can you please elaborate and write it as an answer?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch An MRE is hardly required for this question

Comment: Why do we need to store Polynomials or very large numbers in Linked lists? Why can't we use this way for those applications?

Comment: @jarmod Yep, but if you interpret it as "what are the pros and cons of arrays vs linked lists" then it's a pretty good question.

Comment: You don't need to store polynomials in a linked list, but it's commonly used and is convenient. One reason is the need to represent arbitrary valued coefficients.

Comment: *"Why do we need to store Polynomials or very large numbers in Linked lists? Why can't we use this way for those applications?"* - It's possible to do, so the "why" question becomes pointless.

Comment: You use an array when fast (constant-time) indexed lookup is important, and inserting or deleting elements in the middle is less important.  You use a linked list in the opposite case: when inserting/deleting is important, but indexing less so.

Comment: I'm not sure about polynomials, but when I'm implementing very large (aka arbitrary precision) numbers, I *always* use arrays.

Comment: @SteveSummit nope, have you watched that Stroustrup video... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is linked lists better than arrays?

They are not. They are better in some ways and less good in others.

Pros for linked lists:

- Add and remove elements in constant time. However, this requires that you have found the place where to perform the action. Finding n:th element is O(n)
- Doesn't need a continuous memory block

Pros for arrays:

- Requires less memory (one or two pointers per element)
- Much more cache friendly (all data is continuous)
- Lookup for n:th element in constant time

There are some compromises that can combine many of the two worlds. If you have an overallocated array and a pointer to first and last element, you can add and remove from the endpoints in constant time. At least for a while.

> Why can't I store everything in contiguous memory using pointer arithmetic and malloc()

You can

> and using null character to represent end of list (like in array)?

That is typically not done, with the exception of c-strings which are defined to be null-terminated. But this approach is not common for arrays in general, even though it's possible.

Comment: why do i have to store polynomial terms or digits of a large number in a linked list? Why cant i use this approach for it.

Comment: @ZohaibHamdule You can use arrays for that

Comment: @ZohaibHamdule _"why do i have to store polynomial terms or digits of a large number in a linked list?"_ __Who__ says that you have to use a linked??